# Phone number is not coming to gmail inbox - PHP

Tags: php, gmail, contact-form

Phone number is not coming to gmail inbox. 
It shows some error message (**Warning: Missing argument 5 for sendemail() on line 84 and defined in line 61)** while sending. Phpmailer folder using from github.
Tried many things no solution yet.

```
<?php
  $msg = "";

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body, $phone, $attachment = "")// line 61 {
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
      $mail->addAddress($to);
      $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
      $mail->Phone = ($phone);// argument 5
      $mail->Subject = 'Naukriglobal.com - Email- Resume';
      $mail->Body = $body;
      $mail->isHTML(false);

      return $mail->send();
    }

    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];


    $file = "attachment/" . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
        if (sendemail('hameed.basha278@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $phone, $file)) {
        $msg = 'Email sent!';
        sendemail('hamidsince1990@gmail.com', 'NEW', 'RESUME', 'hey, we have received new email');//line84
      } else
        $msg = 'Email failed!';
    } else
      $msg = "Please check your attachment!";
  }
?>

<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input class="name1" type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Name..." required><br>
      <input class="email1" type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email..." required><br>
      <textarea class="text1" name="body" placeholder="Message..." required></textarea><br>

    <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="15" placeholder="phonenumber" required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />

  <h3 class="h3">Upload Resume </h3>
  <input class="fileattach" type="file" placeholder="upload resume" name="attachment" required><br></input>
  <input class="submit1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

Comment: How many parameters do you count on line 84? I count 4.

Comment: yes four..why ?

Comment: The function you're having trouble with requires 5, which is exactly what the error message says.

Comment: now errot not showing and same time email sent successfully but not getting phone number only in mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$phone` is a required argument for your `sendmail` function.  You need to provide it with a value.

It is being set using the `$_POST` value associated with the `phone` key.  This may or may not exist.  Use the `isset` function to check if the value is set.

You then have several choices:

1.Provide a default value for `$phone` if it isn't set

```
$DEFAULT_PHONE = "800-555-1212";
...
$phone = $DEFAULT_PHONE
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}
```

2.Don't pass in a value for `$phone` if it isn't set and provide a default value as part of the function

```
function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body, $attachment = "", $phone = "800-555-1212")
...
if (!isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    if (sendemail('hameed.basha278@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $file)){
    ...
    }
    ...
} else
    if (sendemail('hameed.basha278@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $file, $phone)){
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

3.Ensure that the values posted to this page always provide a value for `$_POST['phone']`

That is, change the form validation on the page prior to this one to enforce that a user MUST provide a value for `$_POST['phone']` by using a `required` property on the `input`:

```
<input type='tel' name='phone' id='phone' required />
```

Comment: Am beginner, i little bit confused.

Comment: I added additional details/examples to expand on the answer.  Hopefully this will clarify for you.

Comment: Now, its successfully sent email with no error message..But am not getting phone number in mail..need to check in $phone area. any suggestions ?

Comment: The choice was yours as to how to fix the problem.  I probably would have selected the first option, but it all depends on your criteria.  

For the phone, I just realized that you are doing this: `$mail->Phone`.  There is no such property (phone) for the [PHPMailer object](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html).  If you need the phone, then you will need to append it to the email body.

Comment: i tried some append it into email body but failed :'(

Comment: To append in PHP, you will code based upon something like this: `$mail->Body = $body . $phone;`

Comment: Its works :) Thanks a lot. keep in touch with me please. best response.

Answer (score 0):

1.) In your code where `function sendemail` starts `{` is commented, hopefully that's correct in your code.

2.) Change the phone input line to below and retry

```
 <input type="tel" name="phone"> placeholder="phonenumber" required><br>
```